# Street view without cbll

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I need to embed a street view of the Google Maps with specifying a location (actual address) without the latitude and longitude.
I have looked in the URL params and it requires the `cbll` for latitude and longitude, which I do not have.

This is the URL I used

```
https://maps.google.com.au/maps?ie=UTF8&q={ADDRESS}&iwloc=near&t=m&cbp=13,,,,&layer=c&panoid=0&source=embed&output=svembed
```

{ADDRESS} is swapped with actual address.
Would appreciate any comments in this regard

savindya

Answer (score 0):

You need to first use the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) to translate the address into Latitude and Longitude before you make the request to the street view API.